# Will Google index a PHP header redirect?

Tags: php, search-engine-indexing, googlebot

I have a new domain which has an `index.php` file. Inside this file, I get user's IP, save it and redirect to another page on another domain. So there is no output, only header info. Will Google index this domain?

Comment: Google indexed a whole bunch of our PHP redirects and I'm currently fixing it. They indexed our URLs and the destination URLs, page descriptions, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they will not. Search engines follow redirects and the final landing page gets credit for any links, etc, that the original URL has. So that first domain will have no SEO value. So doing this like having a keyword rich domain redirect to another domain has no value and isn't worth doing (as an example).

To follow up on this, search engines don't see nor care where a redirect comes from. So a redirect from PHP or htaccess or something else are all the same to them.

Comment: What if users have to go through a 'gateway' page to access any sub-pages of the site? (i.e., forced to "sign in gateway" before they can proceed to actual content.) Would search engines see both pages or just the 'gateway' page?

Comment: They'll just see the first site since they can't get past the login.